# How to retrieve an Enums value as a string in C#

Tags: c#, enums, examine

I have the following enum:

```
public enum DocumentState
{
    Default = 0,
    Draft = 1,
    Archived = 2,
    Deleted = 3
}
```

Most places in my solution I use it as a normal enum. Some places I use at an int casting it like this:

```
(int)DocumentState.Default)
```

But then, some places, as for example when I work with Examine (who only accepts strings, and not ints as inputs), I need to pass on the enumns int value as if it was a string. This can be done in the following way:

```
((int)DocumentState.Default).ToString()
```

My question is now; can it really be true that there is no other way to retrieve the enums value as a string?

I know that I might be abusing the Enum, but sometimes this is the best approach in the given case.

Comment: Does `DocumentState.Default.ToString()` not work?

Comment: DocumentState.Default.ToString() returns "Default"

Comment: Not really. what is so bad with this/your approach. You could drop enums and use a Dictionary<int,string> instead

Comment: I tend to agree that you're abusing Enums here.

Comment: @Jehof it just seemed kinda wrong when I wrote it. As others have said, it felt like I was abusing the Enum

Comment: Why do you need to use the int value of the enum at all? Maybe you should consider to use a real class which has a `DocumentState`- and an `int` property, for example `ID`. If you need that as string a `document.Id.ToString()` is very readable and reliable

Comment: There is an Enum.GetValues that return an array of integers, but difficult to see any usefulness here

Comment: Are you open to options other than Enums? Or are you so entrenched in your code that a move to something else would be far too time consuming?

Comment: @DrewKennedy: yes, but it depends on what purpose the int value should have

Comment: @DrewKennedy Other options them Enums might also be viable yes. I just don't have the complete overview over de implications of a shift from Enums as I'm not the original developer of that part of the code

Comment: @DrewKennedy: added [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36499206/284240) of a class. Much more code but very easy to maintain and to extend if you need it. So more robust and resuable than a simple enum. You could also simplify it by storing the `StateId` directly in the document class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `DocumentState.Default.ToString("d")`.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're the only one who answered the OP's actual question. Having said that, I'm not sure whether `val.ToString("d")` is preferable to `((int)val).ToString()`.

Comment: Well, C-style casts always make _me_ cringe ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you abuse enums. If you need to store additional informations use real classes. In this case your `Document`-class could have a `State`-property that returns an instance of a `DocumentState` class which has a property for the `DocStateType`-enum. Then you could add additional informations like a `TypeId` if necessary and the code to get a string is very simple and readable:

```
public class Document
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public DocumentState State { get; set; }
    // other properties ...
}


public enum DocStateType
{
    Default = 0,
    Draft = 1,
    Archived = 2,
    Deleted = 3
}

public class DocumentState
{
    public DocumentState(DocStateType type)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.TypeId = (int) type;
    }
    public DocumentState(int typeId)
    {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof (DocStateType), typeId))
            this.Type = (DocStateType) typeId;
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Illegal DocStateType-ID: " + typeId, "typeId");
        this.TypeId = typeId;
    }

    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public DocStateType Type { get; set; }
    // other properties ...
}
```

If you want the `TypeId` as string you just need `doc.State.TypeId.ToString()`, f.e.:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.State = new DocumentState(DocStateType.Default);
string docTypeId = doc.State.TypeId.ToString();
```

This approach uses the enum value as `TypeId`, normally you wouldn't use the enum value for your business logic. So they should be independent.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I think what you're trying to do with your Enum isn't the greatest approach. What you could do is create a class that has a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` to hold your keys and values.

In C# 6 or later:

```
static class DocumentState {
    public static Dictionary<string, int> States { get; } = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "Default", 0 }, { "Draft", 1 }, { "Archived", 2 }, { "Deleted", 3 } };
}
```

C# 5 or lower:

```
class DocumentState {
    public Dictionary<string, int> State { get; }

    public DocumentState() {
        State = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "Default", 0 }, { "Draft", 1 }, { "Archived", 2 }, { "Deleted", 3 } };
    }
}
```

This way you can call your dictionary key at any time to retrieve the desired value, and not mistakenly override the default value of the Dictionary.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Enum.GetName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) method

Comment: I'm not interested in the name or a description, but rather the value of the enum

Answer (score -3):

You can reference `System.Runtime.Serialization` and use the `EnumMember` attribute.

```
public enum foonum
{
    [EnumMember(Value="success")]
    success,
    [EnumMember(Value="fail")]
    fail
}

Console.WriteLine (foonum.success);
```

yields: "success"

Comment: OP just cares about the int value of the enum but as string.

Comment: I guess none of us read the question.